# Can't get Reflect.metadata to work in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reflect-metadata

I have this Typescript code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

export const formatMetadataKey = Symbol("format");

export function format(formatString: string)
{
  return Reflect.metadata(formatMetadataKey, formatString);
}

export function getFormat(target: any, propertyKey: string)
{
  return Reflect.getMetadata(formatMetadataKey, target, propertyKey);
}

class MyData
{
  @format("dd.MM.yyyy")
  dateString: string = "";
}
```

Later in the code, in another file, I have a ReactJs component that takes an instance of `MyData`

```
const MyComponent = (props) =>
{
   const { data } = props;

   // trying to see if a property has a certain decorator here
   const meta = getFormat(data, "dateString");

   ...
}
```

Tried a gazillion different things, but `getFormat` always outputs `undefined` instead of the metadata.

Comment: Do you compile your code using TSC or is it a babel pipeline or other?

Comment: @adsy I am compiling with TSC

Comment: Did you do `import 'reflect-metadata'`? Your actual code looks fine on the face of it I think this could be a setup/build issue. Ive seen this before but only on things like create-react-app or anything that has a babel pipeline so that's ruled out, hmm

Comment: Make sure `emitDecoratorMetadata` is set to true in your tsconfig.

Comment: @adsy Yes, I have import 'reflect-metadata' and yes, I put "emitDecoratorMetadata": true in tsconfig.json. Still the same result.